# How to open executable exactly like in terminal by clicking

Tags: terminal, copy, click, invoke, behavior

I am on Linux Mint (LMDE 4, Buster) and I have a binary executable file which runs fine if opened in Terminal. However if I click this file from graphical interface it does not. Since the binary hasn't changed meanwhile, it must have something to do with how it was invoked. So... How do I get a carbon copy of the Terminal-behaviour by clicking on this goddamn file. Thank you in advance.

Additional info:
I have also already tried to change the OS-behaviour in *FileManager > Settings > Behaviour > Run executable textfiles* and changed permission to Read/Write for current user from the graphical(!) interface. If it is binary itself - although I doubt it - I am fine with simulating or faking that it was invoked by Terminal.

EDIT:
I have the assumption, that it has something to to with a path exported by .bashrc which doesn't reach out to the whole system. However, I don't know how to do that either. I am pretty irritated if that's a Linux policy. I don't see any contribution to security.

EDIT2:
In terminal - where it works - the binary is run **without** sudo

EDIT3:
Now I have uninstalled and reinstalled the application under /opt/ which needs higher privileges. Now I get the same error on clicking but terminal complains about "Cannot connect to X Server"

Answer (score 0):

Try on the terminal:

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

Then try double clicking

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work. Tried with and without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Alright here is what I did - but since I don't really understand what is happening in the background fixing it, don't consider it as solution. At least I don't...

I created my own executable bash-script from terminal with

```
sudo nano myexecutable.sh
```

inside this file I put:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ALREADY_IN_BASHRC_EXPORTED_PATH=$ALREADY_IN_BASHRC_EXPORTED_PATH:"/home/me/path_to_dependency_of_binary"
gnome-terminal -- bash -c '/home/me/path_to_binary/mybinary'
```

then I changed the owner of this newly created script from "root" to "me" via

```
chown me myexecutable.sh
```

made it executable via

```
chmod a+x myexecutable.sh
```

and created a (desktop-)launcher for this new file with option "run in terminal" activated.

Now just my two cents... I have no clue whether the additional export or this weird procedure fixed it for me. Yeah, I know Linux is for free and I don't have to use it - *so don't complain!* - so I won't. But all the Linux Fanboys should really take a second to think about what really happened here. From my point of view this is just ridiculous and I actually strongly support the whole open source idea.